# How to import all files of a folder at once?

Tags: import, files-and-directories, text

I know how to import one textfile by calling its name

```
filestring = Import["myfile.tex", "Text"];
```

Then "filestring" is a string with the myfile content.

How do I import *all* N text files in one folder? So that I get, for example, a list with N strings.

---

Bonus: Can I maybe also not only import all at once but specify "get the last three text files" or "get the first ten" out of that folder into my list?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Have a look at [`FileNames`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FileNames.html):

```
files=FileNames["*.pdf", NotebookDirectory[]]
```

> {"a.pdf","b.pdf","c.pdf"}

will get you a list of all files in the directory where your notebook resides (of course you can choose any path) that match "*.pdf". You can then import the files like this:

```
Import[#]&/@files
```

or if you want certain files (look at the help for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) and [`Span`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Span.html)):

```
Import[#]&/@files[[-3;;-1]] (*last three files*)
Import[#]&/@files[[1;;10]]  (*first ten files*)
```

If you want to use more arguments with `Import` like in your question then you can add them after the `#`, e.g. like this: `Import[#,"Text"]&/@files`. Otherwise you can save typing effort by choosing the the shorter version `Import/@files` (as pointed out by @AlbertRetey).

Comment: Ya, I figured the rest before the edit myself, thanks. I now ended up with: FileNames["*.tex", 
  "MY PATH"];
Part[%, 1 ;; 3];
Import[#, "Text"] & /@ %

Comment: Consider also using `Select`, as you can weed out directories via `Select[ FileNames[...], !DirectoryQ[#]&]`, or if they wish to exclude hidden files (i.e. starting with a "." on a unix/linux based system - mac included), the predicate can be expanded to `!(DirectoryQ[#] || StringMatchQ[#, "." ~~ ___])&`.

Comment: @NickKidman sidenote: using `%` (aka `Out`) can result in confusion if you don´t take care of the evaluation order (e.g. if you do not put all depending code into one cell).

Comment: @YvesKlett: is there a certain reason to use `Import[#]&/@files` instead of the simpler `Import/@files`?

Comment: @AlbertRetey I just wanted to show the way if the OP wanted to use `Import` with additional arguments or options.

Comment: @YvesKlett, I see, he even used that case in his example, as I've just seen. Probably it would make sense to explain that, but the answer is definitely good enough to be accepted as it is :-)

Answer (score 5):

Well, I dug out this question because I accidentally found another way for getting the paths of files today and I can't help posting it as an answer somewhere XD.

It should be mentioned that, [this help page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAFilePath.html) has already told us some ways to insert paths without any *Mathematica* code while it doesn't tell us that there's a even simple way to get the paths of the files, that is:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Now the whole process will be quite simple, first input this incomplete code in the notebook:

```
Import /@ {}
```

Then find the files you suppose to import and select them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, etc. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and move to the code above, place the cursor between the `{}` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, run the code and you'll get the expected result.

I think this solution is as fast as, or even faster than the solutions with *Mathematica* codes especially when we only want to input a single file or the name of the target files are not so regular.

Here's a screencast:

[image]

I've tested this solution in *v8* and *v9* on *Windows* platform. Not sure if it will work with other versions and operation systems.

Comment: Doesn't work on a mac. Also, when you paste it, it inserts it as a symbol, not a string and doesn't place a comma between multiple strings. So you'll have to manually insert the quotes and commas to use this... waay too much work.

Comment: This also doesn't work right on Windows 7 with v7, as the strings are inserted without properly escaped backslashes and without commas separating, **BUT** it works if using [Szabolcs's Paste Tabular Data palette.](http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php) (Table button.)

Comment: @rm-rf I supplied the version information of my Mathematica and a snapshot: those commas and backslashes and quotes are not added by me.

Comment: @xzczd  Works as described on 10.0.2 on Win 7.  Doesn't work with 10.0.2 on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: What about using something like `Import[SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]]` (or the version with `Map[]` if you expect to import multiple files)?

Comment: @J.M. I think it's a bit less flexible, because `SystemDialogInput` will always open `Directory[]`.

Answer (score 3):

I actually always use the `FileNames` approach as Yves suggested which gives you better control about which files to import. For completenes I just wanted to add that `Import` itself knows about directories. The following will show all files from a directory (warning: this traverses all subdirectories recursively!):

```
 Import[dirname]
```

and this will import the contents of all text files in a given directory (and all subdirectories):

```
 Import[dirname,"*.txt"]
```

see the documentation in "ref/format/Directory" for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The way how I do it is to firstly generate the name of the input files into a table of strings, here's an example

```
nameInput = Table[StringTemplate["/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t`t`_a`a`.dat", InsertionFunction -> (ToString@NumberForm[#, {2, 2}] &)]@<|
 "t" -> 0.01 k, "a" -> 0.01 l|>, {k, 1, 3}, {l, 0, 4}];
```

which produces the following

```
  {{"/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.01_a0.00.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.01_a0.01.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.01_a0.02.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.01_a0.03.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.01_a0.04.dat"}, 
  {"/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.02_a0.00.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.02_a0.01.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.02_a0.02.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.02_a0.03.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.02_a0.04.dat"}, 
  {"/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.03_a0.00.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.03_a0.01.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.03_a0.02.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.03_a0.03.dat", 
  "/Users/Projekt/output/input/b5_t0.03_a0.04.dat"}}
```

This works well especially when your input files follows a pattern.
Then you can simply import your data by importing the table

```
data = Table[Import[nameInput[[i, j]]], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 4}];
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Make a super simple program:

```
importdat := (# // Import[#, "Table"] &) &
```

and then use:

```
FileNames["*"] // importdat /@ # & // (nameofdataset = #) &;
```

you can narrow down the dataset to one with specific string by playing with *

Comment: Might be better to use `FileNames["*.txt"] ` or whatever other file type you are trying to import.

Comment: This is not super simple at all. Your importdat definition in unnecessarily complicated. You can replace it with importdat := Import[#, "Table"] & and it will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For some basic data files, imported in such a way that each can be plotted, consider this sort of delimited file:

```
{0, 0}
{1/4, 0.05262298820443631}
{1/2, 0.0708342218540585}
{3/4, 0.0828484992154531}
```

Then, use, with the file stored in `fold1` (in the right directory on your computer, here this is `home/Downloads/data/`),

```
files = FileNames["*.txt", "/home/Downloads/data/fold1"]
datlist = ToExpression[Import[files[[#]], "List"]] & /@ Range[Length@files]
```

to get at all the files, then e.g.

```
ListPlot[datlist[[1]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]