# Import a given column from an excel file?

Tags: import

It seems that I can get the first column of excle data, say "test.xls", if I know the total length...

```
data = Table[{i}, {i, 6}];
Export["test.xls", data];    
Import["test.xls", {"Data",1,Range[len],1}]
```

But the problem is, If I don't know the total length, can I do the same thing? especially consider the data scale is quite large.

Comment: Can you provide a small example xls to ease answering?

Comment: @Philipp updated with data filled in test.xls.

Comment: @Öskå the real range is set by `Range[len],1` thus this will import first column with row from 1 to the `len`. Although the results is a row, quite strange.

Comment: Saving as csv is no option?

Comment: @Öskå Aha, yes, your code work for me and solved my problem. But why my `Import["test.xls", {"Data", 1, ;; , 1}]` don't work???

Comment: @Öskå unless this is a duplicate, you might consider answering,  this could ve useful for future visitors.

Comment: @Öskå please form your solution into an answer, as Yves Klett proposed.

Comment: @vanabel here are some examples that use span as part of the Import parameters http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/how-to-import-all-files-of-a-folder-at-once/5243#5243

Comment: IIRC its actually faster to import the whole thing and extract what you need that is instead of putting the range inside import just do : `Import["file.xls"][[1,;;,1]]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is here: [`Import a Spreadsheet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ImportASpreadsheet.html).

> [image]

Thus you can use:

```
Import["~/test.xls", {"Data", 1, All, 2}]
```

The syntax in your case is `{"Data", # of sheet(s), # of row(s), # of column(s)}`.

Answer (score 2):

Its easy:
just look at the structure of your imported data.
Since you did not provide a file, we will use example data from Wolfram:

```
tab = Import["ExampleData/elements.xls"]
{{{"AtomicNumber", "Abbreviation", "Name", "AtomicWeight"}, {1., "H", 
"Hydrogen", 1.00793}, {2., "He", "Helium", 4.00259}, {3., "Li", 
"Lithium", 6.94141}, {4., "Be", "Beryllium", 9.01218}, {5., "B", 
"Boron", 10.8086}, {6., "C", "Carbon", 12.0107}, {7., "N", 
"Nitrogen", 14.0067}, {8., "O", "Oxygen", 15.9961}, {9., "F", 
"Fluorine", 18.9984}}}'
```

Now you see, there is a first bracket spreading the tables of the spreadsheet. Here only one. Then rows and then columns. Hence, what you want is the first column of the first table in the spreadsheet:

```
tab[[1, All, 1]]
{"AtomicNumber", 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.}
```

to look at the example spreadsheet, you can save it by using:

```
Export["test.xls", Import["ExampleData/elements.xls"]]
```

Comment: @Öskå exactly!!

Comment: Can't you just save as csv and then read until you leave the first column?