# Import Excel with variable row number

Tags: import, excel

i am importing some Excel coloumns, what perfectly works.
Unfortunatly i am current setting the range `Range [2, 50]` statically

```
import = Import["/Users/Tool/Import.xls", {"Data", 2, Range [2, 50], {4, 5}}]
```

is there a way to set up this dynamically. Just the number of the rows. The coloumns are fixed in `{4, 5}`

many thanks

Comment: Please format the code in your questions appropriately. Learn [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) how to do that.

Comment: @Sascha: Thanks. Done

Comment: Just replace `Range[2,50]` with 'All'. See duplicate here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71635/6588

Comment: Sorry, but All will not work due i start with row = 2. I know that duplicate and sorry for asking again but i have already coded it and found it out

Comment: Just remove the first row after having imported? See `Rest`: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html

Comment: thanks. the issue is the different data format. But the best would be to manually update the row number. it is less effort as it i looks than all other things provided

Comment: there really is no reason to use the `Import` options to select the range. `Import` the whole thing and use `Part` to save what you want.  There is no performance or memory savings to do it via `Import`

Comment: Is it the case columns 4 and 5 have fewer rows that the rest of the page or what? Please clarify what is your criteria for deciding how many rows to import.

Answer (score 0):

```
istart = 2;
istop = 50;
import = Import[ "/Users/Tool/Import.xls", {"Data", 2, Range [istart, istop], {4, 5}}]
```

?

Comment: ok but how to calculate the istop ? :) That is the key issue i have. I would like to calculate this by run-time if it would be possible

Comment: Depends what you want to set it to! I assume now that you want to set it to the value of the last row containing an entry in your xls? (You've not actually stated that anywhere)

Comment: I'm confused… doesn't *Mathematica* only import up to the rightmost column and lowest row that contains something?