# How to import several files at once?

Tags: import

I tried to import multiple files at once. Following [this topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5242/how-to-import-all-files-of-a-folder-at-once) my code is

```
files = FileNames["*.phz", NotebookDirectory[]]
neki = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ files
```

Now this works perfectly fine. To be completely clear my files have names *"zug1.phz", "zug2.phz", "zug3.phz" etc... up to "zug25.phz"*.

Now the problem is that I don't know the order of the imported files. Meaning `neki[[1]]` opens a file, but the question is, which one? Ideally `neki[[1]]` would open file "zug1.phz". But it doesn't matter, the idea is that I have to know which file is opened or maybe even specify at the Import which file should be under `neki[[1]]`.

Comment: You could use `<| "Name" -> #, "Contents" -> Import[#, "Table"] |> & /@ files`. I don't know about inbuilt ways to do it.

Comment: Mapping preserves order, meaning `Transpose@{files,neki}` should create filename/data pairs that aligned.

Comment: useful: `SortBy[files,  StringCases[#, (n : NumberString) ~~ ".phz" :> ToExpression@n] &]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Details and Options" section of the [documentation of FileNames](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNames.html) states that "The list of files returned by `FileNames` is **sorted** in the order generated by the function `Sort`." so the list will be in lexicographic order, and I suspect that your files will ***not*** be imported as you showed.

```
files = {"zug1.phz", "zug2.phz", "zug3.phz", "zug4.phz", "zug5.phz", 
   "zug6.phz", "zug7.phz", "zug8.phz", "zug9.phz", "zug10.phz", 
   "zug11.phz", "zug12.phz", "zug13.phz", "zug14.phz", "zug15.phz", 
   "zug16.phz", "zug17.phz", "zug18.phz", "zug19.phz", "zug20.phz", 
   "zug21.phz", "zug22.phz", "zug23.phz", "zug24.phz", "zug25.phz"};

Sort[files]

(* Out: 
{"zug10.phz", "zug11.phz", "zug12.phz", "zug13.phz", "zug14.phz", "zug15.phz", "zug16.phz", 
 "zug17.phz", "zug18.phz", "zug19.phz", "zug1.phz", "zug20.phz", "zug21.phz", "zug22.phz", 
 "zug23.phz", "zug24.phz", "zug25.phz", "zug2.phz", "zug3.phz", "zug4.phz", "zug5.phz", 
 "zug6.phz", "zug7.phz", "zug8.phz", "zug9.phz"}
*)
```

---

[Patrick Stevens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/30771/patrick-stevens) suggested a very nice workaround using an [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Associations.html) in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91825/how-to-import-several-files-at-once#comment249547_91825) to your question:

```
<| "Name" -> #, "Contents" -> Import[#, "Table"] |> & /@ files
```