# Importing multiple data files into my notebook

Tags: import

I am trying to import several data files all at once into my Mathematica notebook. I want get all of them together by evaluating one expression (perhaps a Do-Loop).

---

```
testAand1 = Import["/Users/..../momentum_A_1.dat"];
testBand1 = Import["/Users/..../momentum_B_1.dat"];
...
testZand10 = Import["/Users/..../momentum_Z_10.dat"];
```

---

Kindly suggest how I can do it.

Comment: Look up ‘Map’ in the documentation.

Comment: And `FileNames`

Comment: Your example indicates that there are two files with the same name in in one directory. I don't know any OS that permits that, so I think its a typo that you should correct.

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91825/3066) is closely related and may help you.