# Importing .txt files from directory with Do loop

Tags: import

I'm new to Mathematica. I'm trying to write a script that automatically imports a bunch of *.txt* files from a directory into different lists.

The files are labeled *file**XX**.txt* where ***XX*** are numbers 00 to 10.
I'd like to label the lists as *list**XX***. I'm having trouble with 2 things.

1.How to make the loop variable part of the filename and the listname? I tried ***StringJoin <>*** but it doesn't work.

2.How to make ***XX*** 2-digits always? As in 03 instead of 3, and 04 instead of 4, etc.

```
Do[list<>XX<>= Import["/directory/file"<>XX<>".txt"],{XX,0,10}];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: closely related: [5242](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5242/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"] (*make sure to clear all list* variable first*)
Do[
 fileName = "/directory/file" <> IntegerString[n, 10, 2] <> ".txt";
 Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> IntegerString[n, 10, 2]]] = Import[fileName],
 {n, 0, 50}
 ];
```

Then

[image: Mathematica graphics]

etc...

Comment: Ah even better! Very useful if I had files with 3-digit or 4-digit names. Auto padding of zeros with IntegerString rids using If statements. Learned something new. Thank you!

Comment: Will fail the second time you run it.

Comment: Hi @Kuba, could you enlighten me as to why it'd fail?

Comment: @Syira because `listxx` will have values. So `ClearAll["list*"]` or something is needed. Try to run this twice: `Do[Evaluate[Symbol["list" <> IntegerString[n, 10, 2]]] = 
   ToString@n, {n, 1}];`

Comment: @Kuba Ah I see it. I've used `Clear["Global`*"]` at the start, thank you:).

Comment: Thanks @Kuba. I actually noticed this  when I run it next time. Meant to mention it but forgot. I was restarting the kernel before each time when I was testing this. But using Clear["Global`*"] is good solution also. So I added this now to the  answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
list = Table[{}, {XX, 1, 10}]
Do[list[[XX]] = 
   Import["/directory/file" <> 
     If[XX < 10, "0" <> ToString[XX], ToString[XX]] <> ".txt"], {XX, 
   1, 2}];
```

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I needed. Thanks for the help!