# Excel to Mathematica and plot

Tags: plotting, import, excel

I have an csv file that I open with excel. In it 2 columns of numbers. I'd like to import it to mathematica and plot it. How can I do ?

Comment: Mathematica can import CSV files--no need for Excel. Have you search the documentation for "CSV"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the CSV file can be imported programmatically, which has been explained clearly in [document of CSV](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html), but I'd like introduce a more user-friendly approach in this answer.

First, copy the data to *Mathematica* in the following way:

[image]

Then plot:

```
ListPlot@%
```

Comment: @JA: To import data from Excel to Mathematica, you might want to try this: `SetDirectory["D:\\mathematicaSNAcode_Tugrul"]` where `D:\\mathematicaSNAcode_Tugrul` is the location of the Excel or CVS files to be imported. Then `Import["file name.xls", {"Data", 1}]` where `Data 1` indicates that the data will be imported from `Worksheet  1`  in case you have several data worksheets in one Excel file. As Szabolcs indicated, CVS files can be imported in the same way as Excel files.

Comment: @Tebernus As to the capture of file name and directory, there exists user-friendly way, too: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14741/1871

Comment: Thanks for the useful link.